# How to get the value passed to a variable?

Tags: java, jshell, javaparser

I am trying to evaluate a code snippet that has variables initialised to a value. Is there a way to get the field values using java? For the below code:

```
public void testArea(){
    int length = 5;
    int breadth = 6;
    ...
}
```

Suppose this is the code written by a user, I want to check the value of length and breadth from the backend. How to retrieve this?

Comment: those are local variables in a method, outside of the runtime of that method, they don't exist.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify. What kind of backend are you using, how do the the variables get passed?

Comment: I am trying to read the code from a file using javaParser. I want to get the variables declared in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can go check [javaParser](https://javaparser.org)
which help automate your coding in java

```
    JavaParser javaParser = new JavaParser();
    ParseResult<CompilationUnit> compilationUnitParseResult = javaParser
                    .parse(ParseStart.COMPILATION_UNIT, Providers.provider("PATH_TO_FILE"));
    Optional<CompilationUnit> optionalCompilationUnit = compilationUnitParseResult.getResult();
     compilationUnit = optionalCompilationUnit.get();
    List<VariableDeclarator> list = compilationUnit.finAll(VariableDeclarator.class);
if (list.size()>0){
    VariableDeclarator varibaleDeclrator =  list.get(0);
    varibaleDeclrator.getInitializer().get()// this will give you the value of the varible intialized with 
}
```